# Intersecting paths in a directed graph

Tags: directed-graphs

I am stuck with the proof. Computer simulation cannot find a counterexample.

Given a directed graph (digraph)  $G = (V,E)$  and two vertices  $s,t \in V$  called  the source and sink, we assume that there is a simple (without self-intersections)  directed path from  $s$  to  $t$.
Moreover, every directed edge $e \in E$ belongs to such a path. Sink $t$ has no outgoing edges.

To each  $e \in E$  we assign two strictly positive real numbers $c(1,e)$ and $c(2,e)$. We assume (for simplicity) that all directed paths from  $s$  to  $t$  have pairwise distinct sums of numbers $c(1,e)$ and of numbers $c(2,e)$ as well.

The vertex-set $V - t$ is partitioned into $V_1$ and $V_2$.
Let us fix an outgoing edge for each  $v \in V_1$ (respectively, for each $v \in V_2$) and delete all other edges from $v$.
In the obtained reduced digraph  $G'$, determine the directed path from $s$ to $t$ that has the minimum sum of  $c(1,e)$  (respectively, of  $c(2,e)$).
If $G'$  has no directed path from  $s$  to  $t$  then just choose nothing.

Do so for all possible selections of edges from  $V_1$  and $V_2$.

Prove (or disprove) that the obtained two sets of directed paths from  $s$  to $t$ intersect (have at least one common edge).

Comment: What exactly does "intersect" mean?  All such paths have $s$ and $t$ in common, so I guess that doesn't count, but do you mean the paths have a common vertex, or a common edge?

Comment: Sorry for confusion. Intersection means "having a common edge".